# Can a mosquito bite transmit STD's?

Tags: sti, mosquito, syphilis

STDs include just about every kind of infection. Bacterial STDs include chlamydia, gonorrhea, and syphilis. Viral STDs include HIV, genital herpes, genital warts (HPV), and hepatitis B. Trichomoniasis is caused by a parasite. The germs that cause STDs hide in semen, blood, vaginal secretions, and sometimes saliva. <kbd>[source](http://www.webmd.com/sex-relationships/understanding-stds-basics)</kbd>

Mosquitoes can of course transmit malaria, yellow fever and several other serious diseases.

According to [this source](http://health.howstuffworks.com/diseases-conditions/infectious/question700.htm) `(from 2008)` there's no scientific evidence to support the claim that a mosquitoes bite can transmit the HIV/AIDS virus.

There is some limited theoretical evidence which suggests it might be possible for mosquitoes to transmit hepatitis B or C, although there have been no known cases ever, worldwide. <kbd>[source](http://www.hepatitis-central.com/mt/archives/2008/04/can_insect_bite.html)</kbd>

I've also came across an article titled, "[Guy Gets First Ever Mosquito-Borne STD (`Zika`), Gives it to Wife](http://healthland.time.com/2011/04/11/a-scientist-contracts-a-mosquito-borne-virus-and-gives-it-to-wife-as-std/)" <kbd>[source](http://www.treehugger.com/green-food/guy-gets-first-ever-mosquito-borne-std-gives-it-to-wife.html)</kbd>

Diseases spread by mosquitoes only if they can replicate within the mosquito. The amount of disease agent that a mosquito takes in from infected blood is very tiny, and only a tiny fragment of that will be transferred to the next victim. <kbd>[source](https://www.quora.com/Can-mosquitos-transmit-STDs/answer/Joshua-Engel?srid=udZdc)</kbd>

---

Aside from all these sources I would like to get a little more insight on this topic. `Can a mosquito bite transmit STD's?`

If so  `"what std and how"`?
If not `"why?"`?

**Also..**
What STD's are possible for a mosquito to transmit?...
If so `"what and how"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true that Zika can be transmitted sexually (from [the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/zika/transmission/sexual-transmission.html)). However, Zika is generally classified as a mosquito-borne disease, not an STD, as mosquitoes are by far the most common vector of passage. I am not aware of transmission of "typical" STDs by mosquitoes, most likely because, as you say, the amounts of pathogenic material are *extremely* small, and the body's immune system can pretty easily clear it without difficulties.

Many of the organisms that cause STDs (including HIV) are quite sensitive to the environment, and cannot survive for long, if at all, outside the human body, which is why you can't get AIDS from a dirty soup spoon, or even an old bloody bandage. However, mosquito-borne pathogens like [*Plasmodium sp.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmodium) (the parasites which cause malaria) are highly adapted to living part of their life cycle within the mosquito itself, as well as in the human host.